# Asterisk, Ignore DTMF special characters in GET DATA

Tags: asterisk, voip, dtmf, agi, phpagi

I'm using phpagi `$agi->get_data` to read digit from user.
In some telephones, user didn't hit any key, but audio playback immediately stops and get result of `"D"` !!
I searched a lot about it, and looks like `$agi-get_dat` receives DTMF data that contains `0-9*#ABCD`.
1st question is, why my users get `"D"` without hitting any key!
2nd question is, how can i ignore these characters to prevent interrupting my ivr.

Answer (score 0):

phpagi getdata do this call

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/AGICommand_stream+file

so you can extend it by adding allowed digits param. PhpAGI lib is opensource and have source code.

Actualy you can just use stream_file call

> stream_file (line 677)
>
> Play the given audio file, allowing playback to be interrupted by a
>   DTMF digit. This command is similar to the GET DATA command but this
>   command returns after the first DTMF digit has been pressed while GET
>   DATA can accumulated any number of digits before returning.
>
> ```
> return: see evaluate for return information. ['result'] is -1 on hangup or error, 0 if playback completes with no digit received,
> ```
>
> otherwise a decimal value of the DTMF tone. Use chr() to convert to
>   ASCII.
>       link: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki-stream+file
>       example: Ping an IP address
>
> array, stream_file (string $filename, [string $escape_digits = ''],
>   integer $offset)
>
> ```
> string $filename: without extension, often in /var/lib/asterisk/sounds    
> string $escape_digits 
> integer $offset
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately its limited to one digit, right?

Comment: Stream file is one digit. Use exec('Read') if you need more control, incuding play more then one time. Or use background/waitexten, it not stop playback.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the logs by the following command :

asterisk -vvvvv

and you can check the value of the input for example in php code :

$val = $agi->get_data
exec("echo $val >> /tmp/output")

and then check this file : /tmp/output